# How to select unique records with minimum value of specific field in django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a following model:

```
class Product_shipment(models.Model):
    product_dscr = models.ForeignKey(Product_dscr, related_name='product_dscr', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    import_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I need to create an object with unique **product_dscr**. Duplicates should be chosen based on the minimal value of **import_date**. Following SQL code works fine:

```
select id, import_date, stock, product_dscr_id
from shop_product_shipment
where import_date = (
    select min(import_date) 
        from shop_product_shipment as s 
        where s.product_dscr_id = shop_product_shipment.product_dscr_id);
```

Can anyone gimme a tip how to translate in Django?

Comment: What DB are you using? Im asking because you can use distinct(column) if you are on postgresql, which makes things easier.

Comment: @ Марат Туктаров.. Welcome at SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail code and error... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Question moved to editing. Reviewing finished. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @devdob I am using postgresql but I need the object for further work with, not just a column

Comment: If you're using Postgres, why are you tagging MySQL?

Comment: @ strawberry, corrected

Answer (score 0):

following entries made a trick:

```
min_val = Product_shipment.objects.order_by('product_dscr').values('product_dscr').annotate(Min('id'))
out = Product_shipment.objects.filter(id__in=min_val.values_list('id__min', flat=True))
```